# Reaction timer error

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, timer

I'm making a boxing program for school, where you have to punch the enemy knock-out, but the enemy also attack every couple of seconds. It displays a exclamation mark when he is going to attack and you have to react fast to block it.

Basically what I want it to do is to generate a random time after which it executes a command (a attack in my case) when I don't press a button fast enough. A reaction timer in short.

I used multithreading to be able to run the blocking function and enemy attack function at the same time. In the future I would like to add a thread so you will be able to attack.

This is my reaction timer:

```
from random import *
from turtle import *
from time import *
from threading import *

def Reaction(): 
    vTime = 0
    while vTime < 3: #The time in which you have to react
        vNow = time()
        vStep = vNow + 0.25
        while time() < vStep:
            vJack = True #Useless arguments to fill up the time between each step
            vJack = False
        vTime += 0.25
        print(vTime)
        if vReaction == True: #Checking if you have pressed the key
            print("Oke")
            break
    print("af")

def key():
    global vReaction
    vReaction = True

def Block():
    global vTimer
    while vTimer < 5:
        onkey(key, "space")
        listen()

def AttackEnemy():
    global vTimer
    while vTimer < 5:
        vHitTime = randrange(4, 12) / 4 * 1000 # Generating the random time after which the enemy is going to hit
        ontimer(Reactie, vHitTime)
        vTimer += 1


vTimer = 0
vBlock = Thread(target = Block, args = ())
vAttack = Thread(target = AttackEnemy, args = ())

vBlock.start()
vAttack.start()

vBlock.join()
vAttack.join()

print("End")
```

When running the program I get these errors:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programma's\Python\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Programma's\Python\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "G:\test getal.py", line 35, in AanvalVijand
    ontimer(Reactie, vSlagtijd)
  File "<string>", line 6, in ontimer
  File "D:\Programma's\Python\lib\turtle.py", line 3662, in Screen
    Turtle._screen = _Screen()
  File "D:\Programma's\Python\lib\turtle.py", line 3690, in __init__
    TurtleScreen.__init__(self, _Screen._canvas)
  File "D:\Programma's\Python\lib\turtle.py", line 985, in __init__
    "blank" : Shape("image", self._blankimage())
  File "D:\Programma's\Python\lib\turtle.py", line 470, in _blankimage
    img = TK.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
  File "D:\Programma's\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3539, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "D:\Programma's\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3495, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

I'm new to all of this and only just code for a couple of weeks, so I would really want to know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

PS: for the project I can't use extended libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you should avoid mixing threading with turtle if you can get away with just using turtle's own `ontimer()` event.  Here's my rework of your code using just `ontimer()` to control the action:

```
from random import randrange
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

vStep = 0.25 # in seconds
FONT = ('Arial', 18, 'normal')
ROUNDS = 3
TIME_PER_ROUND = 5  # in seconds
TIME_BETWEEN_ROUNDS = 2 # in seconds

def StartAttack():
    global vTimer, vReaction

    magicMarker.undo()
    magicMarker.write("!", align='center', font=FONT)

    vTimer = 3  # you now have 3 seconds to react
    vReaction = False
    Reaction()

def Reaction():
    global vTimer

    if vTimer > 0:  # The time in which you have to react

        if vReaction:  # Check if you have pressed the key
            magicMarker.undo()
            magicMarker.write("Reacted in time!", align='center', font=FONT)
        else:
            vTimer -= vStep
            screen.ontimer(Reaction, int(vStep * 1000))  # recheck in vStep seconds
    else:
        magicMarker.undo()
        magicMarker.write("Didn't react in time!", align='center', font=FONT)

def key():
    global vReaction
    vReaction = True

def Block():
    screen.onkey(key, 'space')
    # disable above event handler in after round ends
    screen.ontimer(lambda: screen.onkey(None, 'space'), int(TIME_PER_ROUND * 1000))

def AttackEnemy():
    global vTimer

    vTimer = -1
    # Generate random time after which the enemy is going to hit
    vHitTime = randrange(4, 12) / 4 * 1000
    screen.ontimer(StartAttack, int(vHitTime))

def NextRound():
    global vRounds

    if vRounds > 0:

        magicMarker.undo()
        magicMarker.write(" ", align='center', font=FONT)

        Block()

        AttackEnemy()

        vRounds -= 1

        screen.ontimer(NextRound, int((TIME_PER_ROUND + TIME_BETWEEN_ROUNDS) * 1000))
    else:
        magicMarker.undo()
        magicMarker.write("Match Over!", align='center', font=FONT)

screen = Screen()
screen.listen()

magicMarker = Turtle(visible=False)
magicMarker.write(" ", align='center', font=FONT)

vTimer = -1  # just to make these exist
vReaction = None
vRounds = ROUNDS

NextRound()

screen.mainloop()
```

Click on the window that pops up to make it active so it can receive keyboard events.

I believe the problem you ran into is Tkinter (underpinning of turtle) interacting with the threads -- if you want to go this route, you might check out [Tkinter and Threads](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm)

Comment: The screen.listen() function doesn't stop the program until you've pressed a key?

Comment: @Rek3beef21, no.  It simply enables the window to receive key events which it is not enabled by default.  According to the documentation, "Set focus on TurtleScreen (in order to collect key-events)."  You only call it once in a program, if at all.

Comment: I almost forgot to thank you for your advice and corrections. Many thanks!!